# closed item set in data mining

Tags: r, dataframe, data-mining

I'm new to data mining with R and i want to find frequent itemsets of a data set using arules package .i found this example but it doesn't work for me .

```
ID <- c("A123","A123","A123","A123","B456","B456","B456")
item <- c("bread", "butter", "milk", "eggs", "meat","milk", "peas")

df <- data.frame(ID = ID, item = item)

library(arules)

trans <- as(split(df$item, df$ID), "transactions")
```

the result that i want is :

```
#   items                    transactionID
# 1 {bread,butter,eggs,milk} A123         
# 2 {meat,milk,peas}         B456
```

i'm getting this error :"Error in df$item : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

any idea for solving this error or another way for getting item set ??

Comment: Why not just `tapply(item, ID, toString)`?

Comment: You haven't created the `df` object i.e. `as(split(item, ID), "transactions")`

Comment: After the above step i.e. if you do `inspect(trans)` should get the expected output

Comment: @Sotos i thought that i need to convert my data in form of a matrix or data frame not string . thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
ID <- c("A123","A123","A123","A123","B456","B456","B456")
item <- c("bread", "butter", "milk", "eggs", "meat","milk", "peas")
df <- data.frame(ID = ID, item = item)
```

with

```
ID=c("A123","A123","A123","A123","B456","B456","B456")
item=c("bread", "butter", "milk", "eggs", "meat","milk", "peas")
trans <- as(split(df$item, df$ID), "transactions")
```

solved my problem. 
thanks @Sotos for helping.